# Installing Software on an AWS EC2 Windows 2019 Instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

Do EC2 instances automatically save changes made inside a running instance?

For example, after creating an EC2 Windows 2019 instance, I login as Administrator using RDP and install some software. If the EC2 instance is terminated or rebooted, will the software still be installed when I restart the EC2 instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In layman terms, you should consider your EC2 instance as a new virtual machine running on cloud. Terminate is used to delete an EC2 instance. AWS [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-reboot.html) say:

> An instance reboot is equivalent to an operating system reboot. In most cases, it takes only a few minutes to reboot your instance. When you reboot an instance, it keeps its public DNS name (IPv4), private IPv4 address, IPv6 address (if applicable), and any data on its instance store volumes.

Answer (score 1):

If you terminate the instance its lost but if you restart the instance all the installed softwares will be there but if you want to create another instance with the same packages installed then you can create AMI out of instance and next time use that AMI to create new instance and all softwares will be preinstalled in the new win instance